# How to indent if Text is softWrapped in Flutter

Tags: flutter, word-wrap

I'm working on an app that displays lyrics for several hymns in my native language.
Each line of the hymn is an individual Text Widget. I want the text to indent if it got softWrapped if user increases the font size to indicate that its not the next line. How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: did you find any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Adding one or more tab escape characters "\t" to your strings may do the trick for you:

```
          Text("\t this is a text string that will have an indentation",),
```